is there a way to use a mirror site for do-release-upgrade?
Apparently do-release-upgrade is hard coded to reach out to ubuntu.com.
This makes no sense to me.  Does anyone know of a way to specify an alternate mirror?
We only use an offline mirror in our organization.   But it seems impossible to upgrade to the next LTS if you can't connect to the outside world because everything appears hard coded to look at ubuntu.com.
Anyone know of a way?

"Apparently do-release-upgrade is hard coded to reach out to ubuntu.com." Reviewing that script, I see no hard-coding there. What led you to that conclusion? Possible XY problem.

There are specific pages (page will vary; but https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release is an example, page being set by your options) that is reached for so as to know what release-upgrades are available (they vary over time); but that is only a single page for details of supported upgrades.  That doesn't impact mirror being used.

hit Win-key, type Software, select Software & Updates icon,
the related settings window will open.
Click on "Download from" and
select Other;
the dialog that opens will allow to select one of world wide sites that apt or apt-get will download from;
automatic selection: Click Select Best Server

